# Bash shell Decimal to Binary base 2 conversion

Tags: bash, shell, binary, decimal

I'm looking for an easy way in Bash to convert a decimal number into a binary number.  I have variables that need to be converted:

```
$ip1 $ip2 $ip3 $ip4
```

Is there a simple method to do this without looking at every individual number?

I would prefer not to have to write a lot of code.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use `bc` as:

```
echo "obase=2;$ip1" | bc
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/BtD9i)

Comment: At the moment i have 
echo "obase=2;$ip1" | bc
echo "obase=2;$ip2" | bc
echo "obase=2;$ip3" | bc
echo "obase=2;$ip4" | bc

and the echo each line is outputing a newline. 
is there a way to have it output tip to tail

Comment: @DanielDC: You can do: `echo "obase=2;10;20;30" | bc | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: @DanielDC: Add a `| tr -d '\n'` at the end.

Comment: lol i totally forgot the  | tr -d '\n' thanks heaps for your help man appreciate it

Comment: Great solution; a slightly more compact (and marginally better-performing) version is: `bc <<<"obase=2;$ip1"`.

Comment: This is a great solution. The explanation is that `bc` is a calculator which accepts input from stdin. In this case, the input is the string to set the base of the output to 2 (presumable the default input is base 10), and then just echo the number in the "ip1" variable. The <<< is just a quick way to pass a string or variable to somethings stdin (ie. it is equivelent to `echo "obase=2;$ip1" | bc` (but presumably preferred since it eliminates the call to echo). A more straightforward example of `bc` adding two and two is `bc <<<"2+2"`.

Comment: In case you're looking for the reversal process, ie binary to decimal, here you go `echo $((2#$@))` where $@ is your binary number.

Comment: How do you specify the number of digits?

Comment: I asked that question here: [How to make `bc` output a desired number of base-2 binary digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71568169/4561887)

Answer (score 60):

Convert decimal to binary with bash builtin commands (range 0 to 255):

```
D2B=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})

echo ${D2B[7]}
```

00000111

```
echo ${D2B[85]}
```

01010101

```
echo ${D2B[127]}
```

01111111

---

To remove leading zeros, e.g. from `${D2B[7]}`:

```
echo $((10#${D2B[7]}))
```

111

---

This creates an array with `00000000 00000001 00000010 ... 11111101 11111110 11111111` with bash‘s [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). The position in array D2B represents its decimal value.

See also: [Understanding code ({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44738494/3776858)

Comment: Very nice pure bash solution! To generalize this for range 0 to 2^n-1, use `eval D2B='('$(for ((i=0; i<$n; i++)); do printf '%s' "{0..1}"; done)')'` (after setting `n`). The only drawback is that this method takes O(2^n) space (superpolynomial!). This quickly draws unwieldy.

Comment: Incredible tight solution! Can you explain what happens? What does `{0..1}` ?

Comment: The output of `echo $D2B` is `00000000` which was confusing me, as this does not look like an array but a simple string. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: @domih: Here `D2B` is an array. I do not recommend using `$D2B` because it is intended to display strings. To access the first element of an array use `${D2B[0]}`.

Comment: simple example to help understand: `a=({0..1}{2..3}); echo ${a[@]}`. The `echo` statement prints `a` for all indices.

Comment: This is really cool, but won't this blow up in memory because it allocates the entire array?

Comment: @bjd2385: Memory consumption is kept within limits with this small array. This shows the complete array: `echo {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}`

Comment: @Cyrus but if I tried this option with a 4 byte arrangement, e.g. to represent an IP address in base 10 for a lookup...it seems to crash my terminal. Very cool though! There are other methods of accomplishing that though to get around this.

Comment: @bjd2385: With more digits the array scales very quickly.

Comment: I never known `Brace Expansion` can do multi-dimensional orthogonal. very impressive!!

Comment: the magic of  `Brace Expansion` x `Array`. you are a bash artist

Answer (score 7):

**Decimal to binary conversion in Bash:**

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 to do this.

Convert the decimals 1 through 5 to binary.

```
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;1"
1
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;2"
10
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;3"
11
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;4"
100
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;5"
101
```

**Bonus example:**

```
el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;1024"
10000000000

el@apollo:~$ bc <<< "obase=2;2^128"
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `dc` for this. It's very concise:

```
$ n=50; dc -e "$n 2op"
110010
```

The commands here are as follows:

1. Push the number, `n`, on the stack, via shell expansion.
2. Push 2 on the stack, then use `o` to pop the stack and use 2 as the **o**utput radix.
3. `p` to **p**rint the top of the stack (which is just `n`), using the output radix set in step 2 (so print in binary).

If you want padding:

```
$ n=50; pad_size=16; printf "%0${pad_size}d\n" $(dc -e "$n 2op")
0000000000110010
```

Answer (score 3):

General method for converting an integer number into another representation with another base (but base<=10 because of using digits 0..9 for representation, only):

```
function convertIntvalToBase () # (Val Base)
{
   val=$1
   base=$2
   result=""
   while [ $val -ne 0 ] ; do
        result=$(( $val % $base ))$result #residual is next digit
        val=$(( $val / $base ))
   done
   echo -n $result
}
```

e.g.

```
convertIntvalToBase $ip1 2     # converts $ip1 into binary representation
```

Answer (score 3):

Defined as a function in bash:

```
# to Binary:
toBinary(){
    local n bit
    for (( n=$1 ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do  bit="$(( n&1 ))$bit"; done
    printf "%s\n" "$bit"
}
```

Comment: Any reason for using `printf "%s\n" "$bit"` rather than just `echo $bit`?

Comment: Many reasons. Please read [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/232326).

Comment: Ew, yeah that's compelling enough I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Decimal to Binary using only Bash**

Any integer number can be converted ti binary using it::

```
touch dec2bin.bash && chmod +x "$_" && vim "$_"
```

And, then copy paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$1;
dec2bin()
{
    op=2; ## Since we're converting to binary
    quo=$(( $num/ $op)); ## quotient
    rem=$(( $num% $op)); ## remainder
    array=(); ## array for putting remainder inside array
    array+=("$rem"); ## array expansion
        until [[ $quo -eq 0 ]]; do
            num=$quo; ## looping to get all remainder, untill the remainder is 0
            quo=$(( $num / $op));
            rem=$(( $num % $op));
            array+="$rem"; ## array expansion
        done
    binary=$(echo "${array[@]}" | rev); ## reversing array
    printf "$binary\n"; ## print array
}
main()
{
[[ -n ${num//[0-9]/} ]] &&
    { printf "$num is not an integer bruv!\n"; return 1;
    } || { dec2bin $num; }
}
main;
```

For example:

```
./dec2bin.bash $var
110100100
```

Integer must be added!!

```
./dec2bin.bash 420.py
420.py is not an integer bruv!
```

**Also, another way** using python: 
Much slower

```
python -c "print(bin(420))"
0b110100100
```

**Hexadecimal to Binary using only Bash**

Similarly, hexadecimal to binary, as follows using only bash:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash ## For Darwin :( higher bash :)
#!/bin/bash ## Linux :)
hex=$1;
hex2bin()
{
    op=2; num=$((16#$hex));
    quo=$(( $num/ $op));
    rem=$(( $num% $op));
    array=();
    array+=("$rem");
        until [[ $quo -eq 0 ]]; do
            num=$quo;
            quo=$(( $num / $op));
            rem=$(( $num % $op));
            array+="$rem";
        done
    binary=$(echo "${array[@]}" | rev);
    printf "Binary of $1 is: $binary\n";
}
main()
{
[[ -n ${hex//[0-9,A-F,a-f]/} ]] &&
    { printf "$hex is not a hexa decimal number bruv!\n"; return 1;
    } || { hex2bin $hex; }
}
main;
```

For example:

```
./hex2bin.bash 1aF
Binary of 1aF is: 110101111
```

Hex must be passed:

```
./hex2bin.bash XyZ
XyZ is not a hexa decimal number bruv!
```

Answer (score 1):

To make [@codaddict's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278539/4561887) a little more pretty, use this to prefix the output with `0b` for "binary":

```sh
printf "0b%s\n" "$(echo "obase=2; $((num1 + num2))" | bc)"
```

Example:

```sh
num1=2#1111  # binary  1111 (decimal 15)
num2=2#11111 # binary 11111 (decimal 31)
printf "0b%s\n" "$(echo "obase=2; $((num1 + num2))" | bc)"
```

Output:

```
0b101110
```

This is decimal 46.

For details on the input base-2 formatting in bash, such as `2#1111` above, see the very end of my answer here: [How to use all bash operators, and arithmetic expansion, in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567705/4561887).

To have at least 8 digits in the output, use:

```sh
printf "0b%08d\n" $(echo "obase=2; $((num1 + num2))" | bc)
```

Source: [David Rankin, in an answer to my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568608/4561887).

Answer (score 0):

```
toBin ()
{
    printf "%08d\n" $(dc -e "$1 2op")
}


$ toBin 37
00100101
```