# Native Decimal to Binary conversion

Tags: bash, binary, decimal

Is there a way to compute the binary representation of a decimal number, natively in Bash, without resorting to external programs such as `bc`?

Example:
Suppose I have `5` in base 10: I want to obtain  `101` in base 2.

Why using `bc` is not an option: loop performance.

Comment: [See this answer on linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25943519/548225)

Comment: @anubhava The question you linked doesn't specify the constrain of nativity. The answer you linked only works for numbers [0, 255] – the comment appended to that answer explains how to raise this limit, however it is pretty awkward and inefficient, so this question should be kept to collect appropriate answers.

Comment: If you edit the question to clarify why using `bc` is not an option then sure this question can be opened.

Comment: I edited the question. The concern however is not "why", but "how".

Comment: What range of input values are you seeking to convert?  How often are you planning to run conversions?  Will you ever need to convert from binary to decimal?  Is using `awk` or Perl or Python ruled out for 'loop performance'?  Have you measured the performance, or are you guessing that it is a problem?  What other calculations are you planning to do?  But mostly — why reinvent the wheel?  If using `bc` is too slow, then maybe shell is the wrong language in the first place?

Comment: No practical constrain on numbers range is of course preferred. Performance becomes a guesstimated concern over anything more than a thousand loop iterations: 2ms per `bc` execution gets tangible. Bash is indeed a quite-enough appropriate language (perhaps not the most one?) due to fast prototyping and easiness of system integration with the large pool of external binaries, custom and "standard" ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's arithmetic operators rather than a lookup table.  For example

```
#!/bin/bash

d2b() {
    local bits=
    local num=$1
    while [[ $num != 0 ]]
    do
            if (( $num & 1 ))
            then
                    bits="1$bits"
            else
                    bits="0$bits"
            fi
            let num=$(($num >> 1))
    done
    echo ${bits:=0}
}

for n in $*
do
    d2b $n
done
```