# Bash script to calculate summarize IP address ranges

Tags: bash, ip, ipv4, netmask

I need to write a bash script that when I enter two ip addresses, it will calculate summarize address for them.

Examlpe:

```
192.168.1.27/25
192.168.1.129/25
```

Result will be:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

Can you help me with this script?

I know you will say to me “What did you try?”

I tried to find something in Google, but what I found that I must to convert to binary then calculate it, and it will be very hard.

I even don’t know how to start with it.

Any idea or hint please?

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Find the smallest network that includes the IP addresses given?

Comment: If i have many subnet, try to  summarize them, (most common address)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TFV2VycauM

Comment: So was that "Yes, I mean the smallest subnet that contains all the given IP addresses"? Or "No, I mean something else"?

Comment: check the video, showing what i need to do

Comment: ok, but why you are angry :)

Comment: [Decimal to binary conversion with bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25943519/3776858)

Comment: You'll need to start by defining and writing down _specific_ requirements. That's as much for you as it is for us, because you cannot solve a problem until you know what the problem is. And, no, linking us to some YouTube video does not count.

Comment: @ceving: No, that's "summing". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/summarize

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculation of common netmask with bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

D2B=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
declare -i c=0                              # set integer attribute

# read and convert IPs to binary
IFS=./ read -r -p "IP 1: " a1 a2 a3 a4     # e.g. 192.168.1.27
b1="${D2B[$a1]}${D2B[$a2]}${D2B[$a3]}${D2B[$a4]}"

IFS=./ read -r -p "IP 2: " a1 a2 a3 a4     # e.g. 192.168.1.129
b2="${D2B[$a1]}${D2B[$a2]}${D2B[$a3]}${D2B[$a4]}"

# find number of same bits ($c) in both IPs from left, use $c as counter
for ((i=0;i<32;i++)); do
  [[ ${b1:$i:1} == "${b2:$i:1}" ]] && c=c+1 || break
done    

# create string with zeros
for ((i=c;i<32;i++)); do
  fill="${fill}0"
done    

# append string with zeros to string with identical bits to fill 32 bit again
new="${b1:0:$c}${fill}"

# convert binary $new to decimal IP with netmask
new="$((2#${new:0:8})).$((2#${new:8:8})).$((2#${new:16:8})).$((2#${new:24:8}))/$c"
echo "$new"
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

Comment: that's some serious bash-fu :)