# How to do binary addition in bash

Tags: bash, binary

I am trying to add two 32 bit binary numbers. One of them is a constant (`address_range_in_binary`) , and another one is an element of an array (`IPinEachSubnet[$val]`)

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/hexa-binary-octal-additions-in-shell-scripting-654260/), but I could not figure out how to get it done using variables. I have been trying to use different combinations of the below, but none of them seems to work. It is probably a simple syntax issue. Any help would be appreciated. The following is printing some negative random values.

For example, if the values are as following:

```
$address_range_in_binary=00001010001101110000101001000000
$IPinEachSubnet[$val]=00000000000000000000000000010000

echo "ibase=2;obase=2;$((address_range_in_binary+IPinEachSubnet[$val]))" | bc -l
```

The output of this is `-1011101110111111110`

Comment: If you're fine with output in hex: `printf '%x\n' $((2#1010001101110000101001000000 + 2#10000))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define your variables (I will use shorter names):

```
$ y=00001010001101110000101001000000
$ t=00000000000000000000000000010000
```

Now, let's run the command in question:

```
$ echo "ibase=2;obase=2;$((y+t))" | bc -l
-1011101110111111111
```

The above produces that incorrect result that you observed.

To get the correct result:

```
$ echo "ibase=2;obase=2; $y+$t" | bc -l
1010001101110000101001010000
```

#### Discussion

The command `$((y+t))` tells bash to do the addition assuming that the numbers are base-10.  The result of bash's addition is passed to `bc`.   This is not what you want:  You want `bc` to do the addition.

#### Using an array

```
$ y=00001010001101110000101001000000
$ arr=(00000000000000000000000000010000)
$ echo "ibase=2;obase=2; $y+${arr[0]}" | bc -l
1010001101110000101001010000
```

Comment: still there is issue when passing the array element.
`echo "ibase=2;obase=2;$address_range_in_binary+$IPinEachSubnet[$val]" | bc -l`

gives

`(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Comment: @tuxebin Please see updated answer for an example of correct bash array syntax.  In short, replace `$IPinEachSubnet[$v‌​al]` with `${IPinEachSubnet[$v‌​al]}`.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` only solution

```
y=2#00001010001101110000101001000000
t=2#00000000000000000000000000010000
oct=$(printf '%o' $(( y + t ))) # no bin format in printf
o2b=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
r=''
for (( i=0; i<${#oct}; i++ ))
do
  r+=${o2b[${oct:$i:1}]}
done
echo $r
```

the conversion from oct to bin is inspired in [Bash shell Decimal to Binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278513/bash-shell-decimal-to-binary-conversion)