# Conversion of decimal to binary format with predefined amount of bits in shell?

Tags: bash, formatting, data-conversion

Yes, I have seen [Bash shell Decimal to Binary base 2 conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278513/bash-shell-decimal-to-binary-base-2-conversion) , but I cannot tell how to do the following easily:

Say, I want to convert the decimal number 47803625 to a 32-bit binary string, that is `0b00000010110110010110110011101001`. Closest I could get to is this:

```
$ printf "0b%32s\n" $(echo "obase=2; 47803625" | bc)
0b      10110110010110110011101001
```

... however, this pads the string on the left with spaces, not zeroes.

(sidenote: if I try the above with the `%d` format specifier, it fails:

```
$ printf "0b%32d\n" $(echo "obase=2; 47803625" | bc)
bash: printf: warning: 10110110010110110011101001: Numerical result out of range
0b             9223372036854775807
```

)

What would be an easy way to do this kind of a conversion from the command line? I'd be fine with a Python or other solution as well - as long as it is a one-liner I can type in a terminal ...

Answer (score 1):

Eh, found it - simply prepend a 0 to the `%32s` format specifiers, then zeroes are used to left pad, even for a string `%s` format specifier:

```
$ printf "0b%032s\n" $(echo "obase=2; 47803625" | bc)
0b00000010110110010110110011101001
```