# What is the bash equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Tags: bash

**In Bash, I would like to be able to both source a script and execute the file. What is Bash's equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?**

I didn't find a readily available question/solution about this topic on Stackoverflow (I suspect I am asking in such a way that doesn't match an existing question/answer, but this is the most obvious way I can think to phrase the question because of my Python experience).

---

p.s. regarding the [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced) (if I had more time, I would have written a shorter response):

The [linked to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced) asks "How to detect if a script is being sourced" but this question asks "how do you create a bash script that can be both sourced AND run as a script?". The answer to this question may use some aspects of the previous question but has additional requirements/questions as follows:

- Once you detect the script is being sourced what is the best way to not run the script (and avoid unintended [side-effects](http://How%20to%20detect%20if%20a%20script%20is%20being%20sourced) (other than importing the functions of interest) like adding/removing/modifying the environment/variables)
- Once you detect the script is being run instead of sourced what is the canonical way of implementing your script (put it in a function? or maybe just put it after the if statement? if you put it after the if statement will it have side-affects?
- most google searches I found on Bash do not cover this topic (a bash script that can be both sourced and executed) what is the canonical way to implement this? is the topic not covered because it is discouraged or bad to do? are there gotchas?

Comment: Not being fluent in Python, I don't understand your question.  :)  Is the idea that you want to be able to detect whether a script was run explicitly, or through inclusion in another script using `source` or the dot operator?

Comment: @ghoti For example I have a script `script1.sh` with a function `xyz()` that I would like to use in another script `script2.sh`. When I source script1 from script2, script1 somehow does an exit that prevents me from ever calling `xyz()` in script2. (a good explanation of the python bit I refer to is provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a script is being sourced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced)

Comment: See also: [Importing functions from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12815774/4561887). I've added a complete [Bash library creation and importing example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241268/4561887) there for anyone interested.

Answer (score 40):

Solution:

```
if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

I added this answer because I wanted an answer that was written in a style to mimic Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'` but in Bash.

Regarding the usage of `BASH_SOURCE` vs `$_`. I use `BASH_SOURCE` because it appears to be more robust than `$_` ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced/23009039#comment16656186_2687092), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684300/52074)).

---

Here is an example that I tested/verified with two Bash scripts.

script1.sh with `xyz()` function:

```
#!/bin/bash

xyz() {
    echo "Entering script1's xyz()"
}

main() {
    xyz
    echo "Entering script1's main()"
}

if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "${0}" ]]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

script2.sh that tries to call function `xyz()`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source script1.sh

xyz
```

Comment: `$0` itself is [not entirely reliable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028#Why_.240_is_NOT_an_option) so I'm not sure this is necessarily going to work either.

Comment: @EtanReisner If you think you have a better solution then feel free to write your own answer. (At this point in time there are 60+ upvotes for answers using `$0` to solve two different problems ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966449/what-is-the-bash-equivalent-to-pythons-if-name-main) )

Comment: I don't. I just wanted to point out that `$0` is known to be unreliable and that that may cause problems here (but likely shouldn't in most cases).

Comment: `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` plays nicer with [igncr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181124/7255) than `${0}` does:

Comment: Upvoted. After about a year of study and usage, I finally agree that comparing `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` against `$0` really is the best technique, as this answer shows, since this technique _properly handles nested scripts, where one script calls or sources another_. If you are like me, though, and want it to look even more Pythonic, check out [my new answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887) which I think beautifies and self-documents it even more.

Answer (score 10):

### Use `FUNCNAME`

`FUNCNAME` is an array that's only available within a function, where `FUNCNAME[0]` is the name of the function, and `FUNCNAME[1]` is the name of the caller. So for a top-level function, `FUNCNAME[1]` will be `main` in an executed script, or `source` in a sourced script.

```
#!/bin/bash

get_funcname_1(){
    printf '%s\n' "${FUNCNAME[1]}"
}

_main(){
    echo hello
}

if [[ $(get_funcname_1) == main ]]; then
    _main
fi
```

Example run:

```
$ bash funcname_test.sh 
hello
$ source funcname_test.sh 
$ _main
hello
```

I'm not sure how I stumbled across this. [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-FUNCNAME) doesn't mention the `source` value.

#### Alternate method: Use `FUNCNAME[0]` outside a function

This only works in 4.3 and 4.4 and is not documented.

```
if [[ ${FUNCNAME[0]} == main ]]; then
    _main
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

There is none. I usually use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

main()
{
    # validate parameters

    echo "In main: $@"

    # your code here
}

main "$@"
```

If you'd like to know whether this script is being `source`'d, just wrap your `main` call in

```
if [[ "$_" != "$0" ]]; then
    echo "Script is being sourced, not calling main()" 
else
    echo "Script is a subshell, calling main()"
    main "$@"
fi
```

Reference: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced)

Answer (score 9):

### `return 2> /dev/null`

For an idiomatic Bash way to do this, you can use `return` like so:

```
_main(){
    echo hello
}

# End sourced section
return 2> /dev/null

_main
```

Example run:

```
$ bash return_test.sh 
hello
$ source return_test.sh 
$ _main
hello
```

If the script is sourced, `return` will return to the parent (of course), but if the script is executed, `return` will produce an error which gets hidden, and the script will continue execution.

I have tested this on GNU Bash 4.2 to 5.0, and it's my preferred solution.

**Warning**: This doesn't work in most other shells.

*This is based on part of [mr.spuratic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706745/4518341) on [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683279/4518341).*

Answer (score 5):

I really think this is the most Pythonic and beautiful way to accomplish the equivalent of `if __name__ == "__main__"` in Bash:

From [hello_world_best.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/hello_world_best.sh) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
    echo "Running main."
    # Add your main function code here
}

if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]; then
    # This script is being run.
    __name__="__main__"
else
    # This script is being sourced.
    __name__="__source__"
fi

# Only run `main` if this script is being **run**, NOT sourced (imported)
if [ "$__name__" = "__main__" ]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

To run it, run `./hello_world_best.sh`. Here is a sample run and output:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash$ ./hello_world_best.sh 
Running main.
```

To source (import) it, run `. ./hello_world_best.sh`, `. hello_world_best.sh`, or `source hello_world_best.sh`, etc. When you source it, you'll see no output in this case, but it will give you access to the functions therein, so you can manually call `main` for instance. If you want to learn more about what "sourcing" means, see my answer here: [Unix: What is the difference between source and export?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887). Here is a sample run and output, including manually calling the `main` function after sourcing the file:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash$ . hello_world_best.sh 
eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash$ main
Running main.
```

**Important:**

I used to believe that using a technique based on `"${FUNCNAME[-1]}"` was better, but that is *not* the case! It turns out that technique does *not* gracefully handle nested scripts, where one script calls or sources another. To make that work, you have to 1) put `"${FUNCNAME[-1]}"` inside a function, and 2) change the index into the `FUNCNAME` arrray based on the level of nested scripts, which isn't practical. So, do **not** use the `"${FUNCNAME[-1]}"` technique I used to recommend. Instead, use the `if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]` technique I now recommend, as it perfectly handles nested scripts!

### Going further

1. I just added a really [Detailed example: how do you write, import, and use libraries in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241268/4561887), which uses my technique above. I also show detailed examples of *relative imports* in Python, so that they will automatically work within a repo cloned onto anyone's computer without reconfiguring anything.

### References

1. [The main answer here where I first learned about `"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967433/4561887)
2. Where I first learned about the `${FUNCNAME[-1]}` trick: @mr.spuratic: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706745/4561887) - he learned it from Dennis Williamson apparently.
3. A lot of personal study, trial, and effort over the last year.
4. My code: [eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash/if__name__==__main___check_if_sourced_or_executed_best.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/if__name__%3D%3D__main___check_if_sourced_or_executed_best.sh)
5. **My other related but longer answer: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662049/4561887)**

Answer (score 4):

I have been using the following construct at the bottom of all my scripts:

```
[[ "$(caller)" != "0 "* ]] || main "$@"
```

Everything else in the script is defined in a function or is a global variable.

`caller` is documented to "Return the context of the current subroutine call." When a script is sourced, the result of caller starts with the line number of the script sourcing this one. If this script is not being sourced, it starts with `"0 "`

The reason I use `!=` and `||` instead of `=` and `&&` is that the latter will cause the script to return false when sourced. This may cause your outer script to exit if it is running under `set -e`.

Note that I only know this works with bash. It wont work with a posix shell. I don't know about other shells such as ksh or zsh.