# how to check if binary is "runnable"

Tags: continuous-integration, cross-compiling, compatibility, cpu-architecture

In my CI-setup I'm compiling my C-code to a number of different architectures (`x86_64-linux-gnu, i386-linux-gnu`, `aarch64-linux-gnu`, `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, `x86_64-apple-darwin`, `i386-apple-darwin`, `i686-w64-mingw32`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32`,...).
I can add new architectures (at least for the *-linux-gnu) simply by "enabling them".

The same CI-configuration is used for a number of projects (with different developers), and strives to be practically "zero config" (as in: "drop this CI-configuration in your project and forget about it, the rest will be taken care of for you").

Some of the targets are being compiled natively, others are cross-compiled. some cross-compiled architectures are runnable on the build machines (e.g. i could run the `i386-apple-darwin` binaries on the `x86_64-apple-darwin`), others are incompatible (e.g. i cannot run `aarch64-linux-gnu binaries` on the `x86_64-linux-gnu builder`).

Everything works great so far.

However, I would also like to run unit-tests during the CI - but only if the unit-tests can actually be executed on the build machine.
I'm not interested at all in getting a lot of failed tests simply because I'm cross-building binaries.

To complicate things a bit, what I'm building are not self-contained executables, but plugins that are dlopen()ed (or whatever is the equivalent on the target platform) by a host application. The host application is typically slow to startup, so I'd like to avoid running it if it cannot use the plugins anyhow.
Building plugins also means that I cannot just try-run them.

I'm using the GNU toolchain (*make*, *gcc*), or at least something compatible (like *clang*)).
In my first attempt to check whether I am cross-compiling, I compare the target-architecture of the build process (as returned by `${CC} -dumpmachine`) with the architecture of *GNU make* (*GNU make* will output the architecture triplet used to build *make* itself when invoked with the `-v` flag).

Something like the following works surprisingly well, at least for the `*-linux-gnu` targets:

```sh
if make --version | egrep ${TARGETARCH:-$(${CC:-cc} -dumpmachine) >/dev/null; then
  echo "native compilation"
else
  echo "cross compiling"
fi
```

However, it doesn't work at all on Windows/MinGW (when doing a native build, *gcc* targets `x86_64-w64-mingw32` but *make* was built for `x86_64-pc-msys`; and worse when building 32bit binaries which are of course fully runnable) or macOS (*gcc* says `x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0`, *make* says `i386-apple-darwin11.3.0` (don't ask me why)).
It's becoming even more of an issue, as, while I am writing this and doing some checks I noticed that even on Linux I get differences like `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` vs `x86_64-linux-gnu`; these differences haven't emerged on my CI-builders yet, but I'm sure that's only a matter of time).

So, I'm looking for a more robust solution to detect whether my build-host will be able to run the produced binaries, and skip unit-tests if it does not.

Comment: Perhaps include an extra unit-test that *is* directly runnable, just a "hello world" or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, and if it fails, skip all the other tests of that architecture?  Fun fact, on Linux at least, a shared library (ELF shared object) can have an entry point and be executable.  (That's how PIE executables are made; what used to be a silly compiler / linker trick is now the default.)

Comment: @umläute: Any remarks/Irgendwelche Bemerkungen ?

Comment: @PeterCordes i eventually ended up with what you suggested. if you can make this into an answer, i would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps include an extra unit-test that *is* directly runnable, just a "hello world" or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, and if it fails, skip all the other plugin tests of that architecture?

Fun fact: on Linux at least, a shared library (ELF shared object) can have an entry point and be executable. (That's how PIE executables are made; what used to be a silly compiler / linker trick is now the default.)  IDK if it would be useful to bake a `main` into one of your existing plugin tests.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your requirements (I will remove this answer in the case I missed the point), you could proceed in three steps:

Instrument your build procedure so that it will produce the exact list of all (gcc 'dumpmachine', make 'built for') pairs you are using.

Keep in the list only the the pairs that would allow executing the program.

Determine from bash if you can execute the binary or not given the pair reflecting your system, using the information you collected:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Credits (some borrowed code):
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317483/array-of-arrays-in-bash/35728122
 
# bash 4 could use associative arrays, but darwin probably only has bash3 (and zsh)
# pairs of gcc -dumpmachine 
# ----- collected/formatted/filtered information begins -----
entries=(
  'x86_64-w64-mingw32        x86_64-pc-msys'
  'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu       x86_64-linux-gnu'
  'x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0 i386-apple-darwin11.3.0'
)
# ----- collected/formatted/filtered information ends -----

is_executable()
{
  local gcc
  local make
  local found=0

  if [ $# -ne 2 ]
  then
    echo "is_executable() requires two parameters - terminating."
    exit 1
  fi

  for page in "${entries[@]}"
  do
      read -r -a arr  <<< "${page}"
      gcc="${arr[0]}"
      make="${arr[1]}"
      if [ "$1" == "${gcc}" ] && [ "$2" == "${make}" ]
      then
        found=1
        break;
      fi
  done

  return ${found}
}

# main
MAKE_BUILT_FOR=$( make --version | sed -n 's/Built for //p')
GCC_DUMPMACHINE=$(gcc -dumpmachine)

# pass
is_executable ${MAKE_BUILT_FOR} ${GCC_DUMPMACHINE}
echo $?

# pass
is_executable x86_64-w64-mingw32  x86_64-pc-msys
echo $?

# fail
is_executable arm-linux-gnueabihf x86_64-pc-msys
echo $?
```

As an extra precautionary measure, you should probably verify that the  gcc 'dumpmachine' and the make 'built for' you are using *are* in the list of gcc, make you are using, and log an error message and/or exit if this is not the case.

Comment: `entries[$((INDEX++))]` seems clunky.  You can append to a bash array with `entries+=("string")`, or you could just do `entries=(` and `)` around the whole block, with lines like `"a b"` inside the block.  That will give you `${entries[0]}` being `a b`, and `[1]` being `c d`, but without an explicit index in the init part.  (It won't inherit an array value from the environment if it's already defined; IDK if that was something you wanted to support?  Starting with INDEX=0 makes that unlikely.)

Comment: Also, you can tighten up the head -2 | tail -1 by folding that into `sed`.  Perhaps with `sed -n s/Built for //p` to only print the matching line (after substitution), so you don't have to strip other lines.

Comment: Yes, it is (was) clunky, and can certainly be perfected -  I am usually using the `entries=()` form myself. The focus was more on the requirements than on a perfect bash script, and had just copied/paste from another script for the sake of the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Oh, also, Bash 4 supports associative arrays, so instead of linear searching and checking key and value, you could set it up so you just check `"${entries[$key]}" == "$value"`.  `declare -A entries`.

Comment: Agree - using those in production on a regular basis. Feel free to edit/improve the script if you wish. Again, providing a state-of-the-art bash script was a non-goal  today. Also I would probably have used the bash construct for replacing a sub-string by "' instead of using sed in order to get rid of the 'Buit For ' if I had spent more time on this answer.

Comment: If the script has to run on apple-darwin, it might be best to avoid bash 4 features.  Or use zsh there?  IDK.  Just a suggestion which could simplify the script and have made it easier to write in the first place.  (The head/tail removal might make it less brittle against changes in exact output format, so I'll make that change, although I haven't tested it.)  I made the simple edits that I'm pretty sure I can get right without testing.

Comment: Disclaimer - I am not (yet) a member of the Apple/Darwin tribe, but I think this is possible to install bash 4 using brew. I would therefore stick with the  requirement of bash 4 being installed, and would add a guard by checking that `BASH_VERSINFO` is greater or equal to 4 at the beginning of the script, and use bash 4 constructs as you suggested.

Comment: Since you already have the code written, I might just keep it.  Performance of linear search is nearly irrelevant for just 3 pairs of entries, vs. the cost of fork/exec.  If anyone was going to significantly overhaul the script in the future, that would be worth a comment (like I included), but creating sysadmin inconvenience for the build machines doesn't sound like a good plan.  You could just as easily say everyone should install zsh on the non-darwin machines that don't come with it by default (I think MacOS does?), so you can use `#!/bin/zsh` which is at least as good as bash in most ways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231655/discussion-between-frant-and-peter-cordes).