# Setting changing env variable from associative array

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to setup a building sh script changing environement variables stocked in an associative array of configurations. I've managed to do the code below, but it seems that imageList contains both Conf1 and Conf2 elements as a simple list. Wich means the currentBuild variable isn't associative.

```
declare -A Conf1
Conf1=( [path]="builds" [file]="file1" )
declare -A Conf2
Conf2=( [path]="builds" [file]="fil2" )
declare -a imageList=( ${Conf1[@]} ${Conf2[@]} )

imageCount=${#imageList[@]}
for (( i = 0 ; i < imageCount ; i++ ))
do
  declare -a currentBuild=${imageList[${i}]}
  echo ${currentBuild["path"]}
  echo "${currentBuild["file"]}"
  #Here comes the future build commands
done
```

Output: builds builds file1 file1 builds builds fil2 fil2

Is there a way to keep the associative array or do it in a more elegant way?

Comment: `do it` What do you want to do exactly? Do you have to use associative arrays at all? Why not use a different form of storing the data?

Comment: I have few variables that i need to use  in order to execute a repetitve set of commands. Each set of commands (in the for loop) will be executed with a specific set of env variable that will change each loop.
In my example for example I would like to:
cd $PATH
cat $FILE
with a changing path and file each loop.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an array of arrays, but bash can't handle complex data structures like that. The only thing you can put in a bash array is strings. BTW, I recommend using `declare -p` (e.g. `declare -p imageList`) to find out what's actually in the variables & arrays you've set.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, your answer helped me find what I wanted there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317483/array-of-arrays-in-bash/35728122