# making an array of user defined vectors to make a user defined matrix in C++

Tags: c++

How do I make a my_matrix using my my_vector class? I made a vector class that have scalar product, addition, dot product functionality, etc. Now I want to create a matrix class that is using vector as it's columns.

### my_vector.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

inline auto& lengtherr = "Not compatible";

template <typename T>
class my_vector
{
private :
    size_t m_dim;
    T *m_arr;
public:
    my_vector(size_t s = 0) : m_dim{s}, m_arr{new T[s]} {}
    my_vector(const my_vector &rhs) : m_dim{rhs.m_dim},m_arr{new T [rhs.m_dim]}
    {
        for(int i = 0  ; i<rhs.m_dim;++i)m_arr[i] = rhs.m_arr[i];
    }
    my_vector(initializer_list<T> list): my_vector(list.size())
    {
        m_dim = list.size();
        int cnt = 0;
        for(auto i : list)
        m_arr[cnt++] = i;
    }
    ~my_vector() { delete[] m_arr; }
    size_t dim() const { return m_dim; }
    void operator=(const my_vector<T> &v)
    { 
        if(v.dim()== m_dim)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < m_dim;++i)
            m_arr[i] = v[i];
        }
        else
        throw length_error(lengtherr);
    }
    T &operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        assert(idx<m_dim);
        return m_arr[idx];
    }
    const T& operator[](size_t idx)const
    {
        assert(idx<m_dim);
        return m_arr[idx];
    }
    T length()
    {
        T temp;temp = m_arr[0]*m_arr[0];
        for(int i = 1 ; i< m_dim;++i)temp+= m_arr[i]*m_arr[i];
        return sqrt(temp);
    }
    void normalize()
    {
        T len = 1/(this->length());
        *this = *this * len;
    }
};
```

and this is my my_matrix class

### my_matrix.h

```
template<typename T>
class my_matrix
{
   
    size_t m_row{0};
    size_t m_col{0};
    public : my_vector<T> *m_mat;
    my_matrix(size_t r, size_t c) : m_row{r},m_col{c}
    {
        /*How do I construct??*/
    }
    ~my_matrix()
    {
        /*destructor*/     
    }
};
```

what I am trying to do is to create my_matrix with my_vectors as columns but How do I control my_vector length while dynamically allocating memory to my_matrix?

Comment: *"How do I control my_vector length while dynamically allocating memory to my_matrix?.."* What does this mean? Provide some sample input and expected output. And also some sample driving code.

Comment: One almost *never* need a pointer to a vector or other container. Why do you think `m_mat` needs to be a pointer?

Comment: say I create object my_matrix<int> m(3,3) now I want my constructor to create 3 my_vector<int> object of size 3 as columns of 'm'.

Comment: Make a matrix class with a member `std::vector<T>` of size (width*height) and create your own indexing functions. Use a 1D vector to store your data to keep values of the matrix contiguous in memory. No need to write any manual new/delete. (Note std::vector is C++'s variable length array, NOT a mathematical vector)

Comment: The naive way would be to use a vector of vectors instead (e.g. `my_vector<my_vector<T>>`). The better way would be to use a single vector or `row * col` elements (e.g. `my_vector<T> vec(row * col)`)

Comment: @PepijnKramer well I can do that but that's not what I am aiming for right now. I want to create my matrix using my own user defined my_vector class

Comment: Sidenote: Never do `using namespace std;` in header files. It pollutes the global namespace for every user of your header file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's a string to show that two vectors can't be added because they are not same in dimension

Comment: @gunslinger Ok, I added it to your question along with the missing header files. Please do the same for the next header if anything is missing there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I completely understood both the ways. Also I have function for scalar prod so when multiplying my matrix with a vector I was hoping to multiply using it. like first col of mat with first element of vector...

Comment: Related: I go over some techniques here: [How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814330/4561887). Keep in mind you can represent an N-dimensional array in any language using a 1-D array for storage. [I do it in Bash here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77677059/4561887).

Comment: So, you could just use a single 1-D vector as the storage for your entire matrix. You'd have to think through the pros and cons of various techniques including this one.

Comment: @gunslinger Note that `new T[s]` leaves the values uninitialized. I suggest `new T[s]{}` to zero-initialize them.

Comment: @GabrielStaples That answer still refers the "C" style way with decaying pointers. And should no longer be used in C++. See C++ core guidelines : [R.2 use raw pointers to denote individual objects only](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r2-in-interfaces-use-raw-pointers-to-denote-individual-objects-only)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, I intentionally made the answer C compatible. I also state at the top that if using C++ it's best to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead. If "you are using C++, it really is best to represent a 2D array as a vector of vectors (ex: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`)", and I link to the answer where I do that.

Comment: @gunslinger `void operator=(const my_vector<T> &v)` --  You do know that the compiler can call `operator=` implicitly?   What if one of those calls gets invoked, and you had no idea it was invoked?  You now have a bug that is very hard to track down, all because your assignment operator does unusual things that are not really assignment.  You wrote a copy constructor, so the assignment operator should do what the copy constructor does, plus delete the existing memory from `this`, (since an assignment operator assigns to an existing object).

Comment: @gunslinger -- If you want a function that "assigns" and checks the size, then create a named function, maybe `assign_to` or `assign` or something else.  Do not use operators where you may not have full control of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is this:

```
my_vector<my_vector<T>> m_mat;
```

use your vector class to store a vector of vectors.

The general rule is that you don't want to manage resources everywhere.  You want to manage resources in classes specialized to just manage resources.  Other classes use them.

Ie, your matrix class should use *some other class* to manage its memory usage.

Now, this - a matrix is a vector of vectors - can work, but it leads to memory fragmentation.

So the second iteration would involve writing a `vector_view`, which wraps a chunk of contiguous memory and doesn't own it.  Then I'd write

```
std::vector<T> m_mat_data;
```

and the columns would be `vector_view`s of a chunk of that data.

A contiguous buffer where you interact with it using vector views gives great performance, as you avoid multiple allocations, get contiguous memory, and avoid needless allocations when doing intermediate work.

Of course, getting this to work well requires a bit of skill.  Your `my_vector` doesn't even have a `const` length method, which is evidence you lack enough C++ experience to make this easy.

The vector of vectors solution is easier to work with at your level of skill, and should give you a good enough experience.  Quite often when writing the contiguous-with-views variant of this I'll write the simpler container-of-container version to validate my more efficient and complex version anyhow.

So write the vector of vector version to start.

```
public : my_vector<my_vector<T>> m_mat;
my_matrix(size_t r, size_t c) :
  m_row{r},
  m_col{c},
  m_mat(m_col) // you have m_col number of columns
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < m_col; ++i )
    m_mat[i] = my_vector<T>(m_row); // the columns are m_row long
}
```

now, `std::vector<T>` has a two-argument constructor `size, T` that if you added to `my_vector` you'd get a slightly cleaner solution:

```
public : my_vector<my_vector<T>> m_mat;
my_matrix(size_t r, size_t c) :
  m_row{r},
  m_col{c},
  m_mat(m_col, my_vector<T>(m_row))
{
}
```

For the view case:

```
template<class T>
struct my_vector_view {
  T* m_data = nullptr;
  std::size_t length = 0u;

  my_vector_view(T* s, T* e):my_vector_view(s, e-s) {}
  my_vector_view(T* s, std::size_t l):m_data(s), length(l) {}
  my_vector_view() {}

  T& operator[](std::size_t i)& { return m_data[i]; }
  T const& operator[](std::size_t i) const& { return m_data[i]; }
  T operator[](std::size_t i) && { return std::move(m_data[i]); }
  // etc
};
```

Then

```
template<class T>
struct matrix {
  std::size_t m_row = 0;
  std::size_t m_col = 0;
  std::vector<T> m_data;

  my_vector_view<T> operator[](std::size_t i)& {
    return { m_data.data()+i*m_row, m_row };
  }
  // etc
};
```

here `matrix[i]` returns a view of a column vector and `matrix[i][j]` returns a single element of the matrix.

We can even augment `vector_view` with a `class stride=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>` and have row vector support as well.

Comment: `my_vector<my_vector<T>>` can't work because `length()` will fail to compile due to `sqrt()`.

Comment: thanks you, Gaining experience is exactly why I am doing it for

Comment: @WeijunZhou Don't call `.length()` then, unless you go off and implement `sqrt(my_vector<double>` ;)