# Bash modulo strange result (not negative)

Tags: bash, modulo

I want to use modulo in a Bash script, but the result is always to low.
I need something like this: days = jdn mod p
this is what i have:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then 
        echo "Fout, syntaxis: $0 maand(in cijfers) jaar"
        exit 1
fi

a=$(echo "14 - $1"|bc)
y=$(echo "$2 + 4800 - $a"|bc)
m=$(echo "12 * $a - 3 + $1"|bc)
jdn=$(echo "scale=2;1 + (153 * $m +2)/5 + 365 * $y +${y}/4 - ${y}/100     - 32045"|bc)
jdn=$(echo "$jdn + 1"|bc|sed "s/...$//")
d=1
p=$(echo "29.530588853")

while [ "$d" != "32" ]
do
        echo -n "$d"
        days=$(echo "scale=2;${jdn} % ${p}"|bc) 
    fase=$(echo "scale=2;$p / $days"|bc)
    fase1=$(echo "${fase}<7.382647213"|bc)
    if [ $fase1 -eq 1 ]
    then
            echo -n "@"
    elif [ $(echo "${fase}<14.76529443"|bc) -eq 1 ]
    then
            echo -n ")"
    elif [ $(echo "$fase<22.14794164"|bc) -eq 1 ]
    then
            echo -n "0"
    else
            echo -n "("
    fi
    d=$(echo "$d + 1"|bc)
    jdn=$(echo "$jdn +1"|bc)
done
```

jdn has as result 2455369, days should be 9.55 but the result is 0.054...

Comment: Where do you define `$m` and `$y`?

Comment: this is just a part of the script, they are defined as: `a=$(echo "14 - $1"|bc)
y=$(echo "$2 + 4800 - $a"|bc)
m=$(echo "12 * $a - 3 + $1"|bc)
`

Comment: Which values do you use for `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: $1 is a month, in this case 6, $2 is a year, in this case 2010

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not used with the forum yet, i will upload the full script in a sec

Comment: You'll be more help if you trim this down to a very small and self-contained example of 1. sample input, 2. required output from that input, 3. any current output AND error messages (exact text!) 4. your code attempt to solve the problem. Right now we are very distracted by all your code and having to dig thru it. I'm not aware of a form of `mod` operator that works on float numbers. Maybe you should explain that also. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic in Bash shell is done with integers only, so it is better to change the approach (or multiply the qantities by a large power of ten to make them be integers).

When you are doing math with integers in Bash, include the arithmetic in double parentheses, or to use a 'let' keyword.

```
((${jdn} % ${p}))
```

as described in these sources.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970559
- [How to use mod operator in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688576/how-to-use-mod-operator-in-bash)

Comment: When i use this, I get the error: 1./maanfase.sh: 20: ./maanfase.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 2455349 % 29.530588853 "

Comment: See if the (( )) helps it in a simplified test script

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine with integers. With doubles, I get the same error.

Comment: modulus is mainly defined for integers (and other algebraic structures, but not reals usually) in mathematics, since the equivalence classes don't work right with non-integers.  How about doing a floor operation on the quotient (assuming numerator and denominator are positive - if signs are not the same, then - abs(top)/abs(bottom) should be right I guess)?  - it may be a math issue and not a bash issue.

Comment: The reason for the error message is that the built-in arithmetic in Bash is integers only. Maybe switch back to `bc` (or to Awk!) if you really need floats.

Comment: Thanks tripleee.  i have no idea what bash does with numbers. tried to fix my answer for the greater good :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: without scale, it works fine. So this is my code:

```
days=$(echo "${jdn} % ${p}"|bc)
```

I only had to make sure that the modulo did'nt give a 0 back and than i could set scale in the division. It seemed to be more a math question at the end...