# Issue with program check if the number is divisible by 2 with no remainder BASH

Tags: bash, division

I tried to write a program to see if the count divisible by 2 without a remainder
Here is my program

```
count=$((count+0))

while read line; do

if [ $count%2==0 ]; then
    printf "%x\n" "$line" >> file2.txt
else
    printf "%x\n" "$line" >> file1.txt
fi

count=$((count+1))
done < merge.bmp
```

This program doesnt work its every time enter to the true

Comment: Try to use arithmetic cmd even here: `if (( count % 2 == 0 ))`.

Comment: `if (( count % 2 == 0 ))`  The test `[` built-in does not support `%`.  Even if it did, there should be whitespace around the `==`.

Comment: What is `count=$((count+0))` for?

Comment: To initialize the variable

Comment: @cdarke I tried to do the if you wrote its still doesnt work.

Comment: @AvielOvadiya:  To initialise the variable, what's wrong with `count=0`?

Comment: @AvielOvadiya: the `if` works for me, what happens for you?  Please don't say "it doesn't work", that's not diagnostic.  Are you sure you are running `bash`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the shell, the `[` command does different things depending on **how many arguments** you give it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test

With this:

```
[ $count%2==0 ]
```

you give `[` a **single** argument (not counting the trailing `]`), and in that case, if the argument is not empty then the exit status is success (i.e. "true"). This is equivalent to `[ -n "${count}%2==0" ]`

You want

```
if [ "$(( $count % 2 ))" -eq 0 ]; then
```

or, if you're using bash

```
if (( count % 2 == 0 )); then
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more "exotic" way to do this:

```
count=0
files=(file1 file2 file3)
num=${#files[@]}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "${files[count++ % num]}"
done < input_file
```

This will put 1st line to `file1`, 2nd line to `file2`, 3rd line to `file3`, 4th line to `file1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

what you're trying to do is a one-liner

```
$ seq 10 | awk '{print > (NR%2?"file1":"file2")}'

==> file1 <==
1
3
5
7
9

==> file2 <==
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
count=$((count+0))

while read line; do

if [ $(($count % 2)) == 0 ]; then
    printf "%x\n" "$line" >> file2.txt
else
    printf "%x\n" "$line" >> file1.txt
fi

count=$((count+1))
done < merge.bmp
```

You have to use the $(( )) around a mod operator as well.

[How to use mod operator in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688576/how-to-use-mod-operator-in-bash)

This will print "even number":

```
count=2;
if [ $(($count % 2)) == 0 ]; then
    printf "even number";
else
    printf "odd number";
fi
```

This will print "odd number":

```
count=3;
if [ $(($count % 2)) == 0 ]; then
    printf "even number";
else
    printf "odd number";
fi
```

Comment: Inside `[ ... ]` the `==` operator is for **string** equality. You want `-eq` for numeric equality.